# What does "subject" means in "subject (a place, text, etc.) to a thorough search in order to locate something."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I read the sentence "subject (a place, text, etc.) to a thorough search in order to locate something." from the definition of "scour". I want to know the meaning of "subject" here. Is it a verb in this case? If so, according to the Oxford dictionaries, "subject" means "cause or force someone or something to undergo (a particular experience or form of treatment, typically an unwelcome or unpleasant one)". How does it make sense? Can someone force a text to undergo a thorough search in order to locate something?

One example sentence is "David scoured each newspaper for an article on the murder."

Meaning: David subjected ??? to a thorough search in order to locate an article on the murder in all newspapers.

Comment: Subject, for better or worse, has multiple definitions. You found a definition yourself that explains the one used in this context. "To force someone to undergo something", in this case it's not a text that's undergoing something but a person.

Comment: @WilliamTheisen Ah! I see the light! That would make a lot of sense. :))

Comment: @WilliamTheisen So the person means himself in this case, right?

Comment: well subject here is referring to whatever you are "scouring", usually a place, maybe you're "scouring your bedroom for you car keys" meaning "subjecting your bedroom to a thorough search for something" (your car keys)

Comment: Subject as a verb takes an object.  David subjected the newspapers to a search.  The prisoner was subjected to questioning.

Comment: Thank you both for the nice explanations :) My doubts have been thoroughly erased. I am now free from getting subjected to the hell of ignorance, even if the word nazis scour the whole city for me.